# adding dlls to a solution and referencing them

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.0, tfs-sdk

I am developing a .net solution. Due to certain complications, I have been asked to add dlls to the solution and then reference the dlls from within the solution.

```
   It works fine on the local box , and builds perfectly on TFS Build server,
```

but when I run it on the server after deploying , I get a run time exception saying :

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Would you know what I should be doing at this point ?
I can provide you more detailed info if needed.. please let me know.

Comment: Simply looks like the server doesn't have `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll` or that it's not in the right place.

Comment: I have the dll within my solution in a seperate folder .. Do we still need the dll on the server ?

Comment: Did you set the "Copy Local" property to True in the reference  for this dll?

Comment: If your app uses a dll it's gonna need to be there. Having it in your solution doesn't really do much unless you've changed the "Copy to output directory" property.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, add the DLL reference through Visual Studio. You should have a "References" folder. Right click on that and "Add Reference" and browse to your DLL.

Comment: @Chris "Copy to output directory" ? Where do I find that ?

Comment: @MarkPM I see that "Copy Local" is set to false for me .. should I change it to true and try ?

Comment: What I mean to write was `Copy Local` like Mark PM suggested. `Copy to output directory` is for files that are in the project but that aren't references. You'll find `Copy Local` if you select the file in the project explorer and hit `F4` to bring up the properties window.

Comment: Yes, when you'll set it to True it will copy it to the bin folder.

Comment: I did change copy local to true, I aslo tried the copy to output directory. I still see the same error message...  Any more suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to get `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll` file,
then **add it as a reference** to your application

this is the dependencies you described:

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two possible resolutions

1. Set CopyLocal property to **true** so that when  build is done local copy of dll is added.
2. Check reference folder has been checked in TFS or not. Sometimes it happens that reference folder is not added in TFS.

Comment: what is reference folder ?